# Dagger - Register class without @Inject with minimal ceremony

Tags: java, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

Lets say I want to register a class with Dagger that doesn't have the `@Inject` annotation on the constructor and that also takes dependencies in its constructor.

i.e.

```
// Java
class MyClass {
    public MyClass(MyDependency dependency) { ... }
}
// Kotlin
class MyClass(private val dependency: MyDependency) { ... }
```

Is there a way to register this class without having to manually wire the dependencies into the constructor?

```
// This is how I currently do it. I must list all constructor dependencies
// and then pass them through to the constructor by hand
@Provides
public MyClass getMyClass(MyDependency depdencency) {
    return new MyClass(dependency);
}

// Something like this is how I'd like to do it
// In this case, the class is registered _as if_ it had the @Inject on the constructor
@ProvideEvenWithoutAnInject
public abstract MyClass getMyClass();
```

Does Dagger offer something like the `@ProvideEvenWithoutAnInject` annotation shown above?

Comment: Using `@Inject` in the constructor IS the minimal ceremony

Comment: No, Dagger can't know which of the possibly many constructors to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't put an `@Inject` annotation on the constructor then Dagger can't create the object for you. You'll need to use a `@Provides` annotated method with a module or `@BindsInstance` with your component to add it. (Or as a component dependency from a provision method if you want more extra steps)